# How can I load a CSV file with " as the delimiter in kdb?

Tags: csv, kdb

How can I load a CSV file with `"` delimiters? See 2nd row. `dd` is loaded in `symbolCol`, not `stringCol`

```
$cat kdb.log
longCol"floatCol"symbolCol"stringCol
1"4"b"bb
2"5""dd
```

I'm loading using

```
tab:("JFSS";enlist "\"") 0: `$"/home/..../kdb.log"
```

and `dd` is loaded in symbolCol, not stringCol

```
q)tab
longCol floatCol symbolCol stringCol
------------------------------------
1       4        b         bb      
2       5        dd                
q)tab[`symbolCol]
`b`dd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually looks like it could be a bug in the parser - worth raising with the Kx team. Using `"` as a delimiter is pretty rare so they probably haven't accounted for it.

The only way around it that I could find was to replace the `"` with a better delimiter. Ideally you should change the delimiter outside of kdb but if you have to do it in kdb you could do:

```
q)("JFSS";enlist",") 0: ssr[;"\"";","]each read0`$":/home/..../kdb.log"
longCol floatCol symbolCol stringCol
------------------------------------
1       4        b         bb
2       5                  dd
q)
```

Use a delimiter that won't ever appear in the file.

Comment: You can still keep the `"` delimiter in the source file in my solution, the code above will just change it after it's read in (at the expense of slightly slower parse time)

Comment: This solution also allows for the last field being missing/incomplete and allows for partial reads (only read a few columns even if the csv has more)

Answer (score 0):

kdb support advised this code.  kdb+ uses double-quotes to detect and ignore embedded delimiters in the file. So instead of using 0: we can parse the csv file as follows.

```
split:"\"" vs' read0 `$":/tmp/kdb.log"; 
headers:`$split[0];   
tab:flip headers!"JFS*"$flip 1_split;
```